# In using has_and_belongs_to_many in Devise, is it user or users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the devise documentation, the correct way to write associations in routes is "user," singular, so that:

```
  resource :user do
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

This makes me think whether devise user model should be different elsewhere as well. What about when it's has_and_belongs_to_many? In model for post, should I write

```
has_and_belongs_to :user
```

or is it users?

Comment: `...to_many` means that conventionally this would be plural.

Comment: With resource :user you are not using a devise route or devise controller. resource :user would expect a UserController and in that case it looks like you want it to be for 1 user. So probally no index to list all users. With the has_and_belongs_to_many it should be users because something can't has many user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check Singular resource [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

In most of the cases, you should use `resources` and `plural`. When you use singular, it points to 'plural' controller as well.

You might want `namespace` or `scope` instead?

For `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you must use plural noun. Like `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`